# How do I neatly word wrap an Email address in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am displaying Email addresses on an HTML page (It is internal so no need to obfuscate)

Long Email addresses are wrapping but they do not look nice

```
donaldduck@exampl
e.com
```

It would be much neater if the line break was at the "@" character

```
donaldduck
@example.com
```

The best I have achieved is by adding a space before the @, but this is not perfect on the emails that do not wrap

```
donaldduck @example.com
```

Is there a way to say "break at the @ character if necessary"?

Comment: you mean you want to make it responsive ?

Comment: You can use the `<wbr>` (Word Break Oppertunity) tag in front of the `@` You need a script to auto insert it in front of every @ if you don't want to hardcode it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add <wbr> tag before punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819939/dynamically-add-wbr-tag-before-punctuation)

Comment: Thank you - I have learnt a new HTML element today.  It worked.

Comment: BTW, the other answer assumes the reader knows they want a <wbr> - I needed to know there was a <wbr> in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this:

```
<p>donaldduck<wbr>@example.com</p>
```

see this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>donaldduck<wbr>@example.com</p>

</body>
</html>
```